# How to get value of array inside another array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I made a php page in which I got the array within array value.

Here is my array:

```
Array (
  [events] => Array ( [0] => 5 [1] => 7 [2] => 8 )
  [fromdate] =>
  [todate] =>
  [description] =>
  [subject] =>
  [fromname] =>
  [replyto] =>
  [senddatetime] =>
  [timezone] => America/Los_Angeles
  [message] =>
  [submit_skip] => Continue
)
```

This array is the POST data from previous page. I want to get `events` value in a variable. How can I do this?

I use this for getting events value but it gives me the array but I want to get first event value

```
echo $eventid=$_POST['events'];
```

Comment: `$_POST['events'][0]`?

Comment: So your real question is: "how to get the first value of an array?" `array_shift`, element at pos 0 `$array[0]`... it's an array dude...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To *echo*:

```
echo $_POST['events'][0];
```

To *assign it to a variable*:

```
$eventid = $_POST['events'][0];
```

To *assign the array to a variable and get the value from the new array*:

```
$events = $_POST['events'];
$eventid = $events[0];
```

`[0]` represents the key of the first value since it is set to be 0.

Comment: or even store the array in a var and access later `$event = $_POST['events']` and `$eventId = $event[0]`

Comment: Yes of course but that just seems tedious unless there is a specific reason for it.

Comment: Well... I imagined the "events" model might be useful, but taking a better look, I guess it's just a list of Ids in a database to get the real models...

Comment: I'll add it because you may be right and it may suit his situation better.

Answer (score 1):

Output:

```
echo $_POST['events'][0];
```

Assign to variable:

```
$eventid = $_POST['events'][0];
```