# Severity: Notice Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I know that this question is ask a lot, but I have a problem, I know that the error give me becouse I am trying to access to a **non-Object**. The problem is that I do not know why this happend.
The funcionality works Ok, but I am trying to make this **OO**, and there is where the problem apears.

**Function 1**

```
$query =  $obj->Searcher($table, $buscar); 
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($query);
    echo '</pre>';
    return array($links, $query); 
}
```

Here, where I do the `print_r` show me all OK, but then

**Function A**

```
list($links, $query) = $this->Function_1($table, $buscar);

echo '<pre>';
 var_dump($query);
 print_r($query);
 echo '</pre>';
```

Here `var_dump` and `print_r` show me instead the value query a **5**, I do not know why, and then when I tried to make a loop or anything of course that give me this error.

```
line 158  --->    if ($query->num_rows != 0) {
                     for ($i = 0; $i < $query->num_rows; $i++) {
.....
                     }
                  }
```

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Trying to get property of non-object
>
> Filename: controllers/test.php
>
> Line Number: 158

Please help, what I am doing wron? Thanks in advance.

**Aditional Information**

This is what the `var_dump` give me

```
int(5)
```

This is what the `print_r` give me

```
5
```

I do not know why because my num_row is **61**

Comment: Please, copy and paste what your var_dump and print_r calls return

Comment: In **Function A**, paste output of `var_dump($query)`

Comment: $query->num_rows, you have an error here because num_rows is a function and you need paranthesis: Replace $query->num_rows with $query->num_rows(); in your if condition and also in for loop.
And the 5 value comes from a small mistake. You forgot to add $ before variable's name.

Comment: @NanaPartykar I edit my question an add the vale that give me

Comment: @KirkBeard what do you think, that when I bring the value this change?

Comment: @KirkBeard I do not think that that answer solve my problem, but thanks any way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my question thanks to [How to get value of array inside another array in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21603888/how-to-get-value-of-array-inside-another-array-in-php)

This is what I do
**Function A**

```
    list($links, $query[0]) = $this->Function_1($table, $buscar);

echo '<pre>';
 var_dump($query[0]);
 print_r($query[0]);
 echo '</pre>';
```

That do not give me more errors and show the results Ok.